# Unable to login to admin page in Heroku production postgres

Tags: django, heroku

This app works locally with sqlite.  When I push it to production with Heroku, I'm not about to login to the admin page.  This is the error I'm getting from debug:

> ProgrammingError at /admin/login/ relation "auth_user" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM
>   "auth_user...

I think I added the correct DATABASE connection string in settings.py (commented out) but that produced the same error.  I've run python manage.py makemigrations and migrate.  Migrate gave the same error.  I found related issues on stack and GitHub but none of them worked.  Most of them just said to migrate.  Any idea what might be causing the error? TIA

**log (last bit)**

```
2018-11-10T02:04:25.402553+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
2018-11-10T02:04:25.402555+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
2018-11-10T02:04:25.402556+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-11-10T02:04:25.402557+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-11-10T02:04:25.403555+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.99.134.157 - - [10/Nov/2018:02:04:25 +0000] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 212013
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
import warnings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from os.path import dirname
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url


BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))
CONTENT_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'content')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # Vendor apps
    'bootstrap4',

    # Application apps
    'main',
    'accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(CONTENT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# DATABASES = {
# 'default': {
#     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
#     'NAME': '<hide>',
#     'USER': '<hide>',
#     'PASSWORD': '<hide>',
#     'HOST': '<hide>',
#     'PORT': '<hide>',
# }

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500, ssl_require=True)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**views.py (where the error is hit)**

```
class GuestOnlyView(View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Redirect to the index page if the user already authenticated
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: "This app works locally with sqlite."

The first thing you should do is make sure that your app runs locally with Postgres. `sqlite` is incompatible with Heroku.

Comment: This is so stupid (I can't believe how many hours I spent trying to figure it out).  I didn't have a great reason to use sqlite over postgres, so after reading your comment I downloaded postgres locally.  I went through the steps, and everything worked perfectly.  So I reset my Heroku database (I didn't have anything in there), migrated, and it worked perfectly.  I think it all came down to something being messed up with the migrations.  I think the proper solution would have been to fake all migrations.